# Compile single file with debug symbols with CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have a project which I am compiling with gcc using CMake Debug mode to be able to debug one function. However, until I reach that function, it takes a lot of time. Is there any way to only compile one single file with `-g -O0` while compiling the rest with `-O2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify single file compiler flags with:

```
set_source_files_properties(the_source.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0")
```

Comment: I guess I previously need to add the file to the sources and then modify the properties, right?

Comment: "add the file to the sources"? If you don't, that means that the file will not be compiled. I see no point caring about compilation flags of sources that are not compiled... I think order matters - I think you need first to add the file to some target, then set source properties, in this order, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yeah, my question was more about if set_source_files_properties also adds the file to the compiled sources. Tested first adding to the sources file and then modyfing the properties, works fine.

Comment: `my question was more about if set_source_files_properties also adds the file to the compiled sources` No, it does not. A source file has to be connected with a target, that results from compiling and linking it with other stuff. You just set it separately.